# Can't install Ubuntu 10.04 or later due to installer error and crash

Tags: installation, ubiquity

This is really, really, really, aggravating. Everytime I try to install Ubuntu (10.04 & up), it works fine up until the point where I actually have to install. It installs about halfway until I get Error #5 & the installer just crashes, bringing me to a live cd environment. I'm pretty sure this is Ubuntu's problem because Linux Mint & Elementary OS (both of which are based on Ubuntu..) install just as they should..

Comment: Adam have you tried to boot to the live cd and attempt to intall from there?

Comment: Have you used the alternate cd?.

Comment: You mention that you can't install 10.04 or later...have you tried any other versions of Ubuntu (e.g., 9.10 or earlier)?

Comment: I have not used the alternate CD, I could possibly try that. And no, I have not tried any earlier versions yet.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).